# HTML email text not displaying correctly in Gmail Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email

I'm finally at the point where my email looks great in all clients... Except for Gmail Mobile. Specifically, it's pushing my nav bar links and footer bar links (Which are tables) to the left, instead of centring them.

Any advice?

Nav bar code:

```html
<td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/tees" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">TEES
                                 </a></td>
                            <td width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/tanks" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">TANKS</a></td>
                            <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ecxh" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/accessories" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">ACCESSORIES
                                 </a></td>
                            <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ecxh" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/sale" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;">SALE</a></td>
                            <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

And my footer is similar to this, except using image links instead of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, it seems that you have used `align="center"` attribute to center the table. I would suggest to use CSS instead of HTML attributes. You can use `margin:0 auto;` CSS property to center an table within it's parent container.

Please see below updated code:

```html
<table class="ecxw320" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
  <tbody>
    <tr bgcolor="#000000">
      <td height="50">
        <!--Use margin:0 auto; to center a table within it's parent container-->
        <table style="margin:0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="20">

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>

              <td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/tees" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;">TEES
                                 </a>
              </td>
              <td width="0">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/tanks" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;">TANKS</a>
              </td>
              <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td class="ecxh" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/accessories" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;">ACCESSORIES
                                 </a>
              </td>
              <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td class="ecxh" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;"><a moz-do-not-send="true" href="https://partofthekult.com/collections/sale" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Helvetica',
monospace;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;display:block;white-space:nowrap;">SALE</a>
              </td>
              <td class="ecxh" width="0">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Apologies, I did not include the full code in my question, nor did I include a screenshot of the current effect.

Here's the full code: [link] (http://paste.ofcode.org/JQS3ykcP7aB9GsZ82Jcu2g)

Here's the screenshot of how it displays in the Gmail App: [link] (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1041/0020/files/IMG_1284.PNG?6670755951936836937)

Comment: @S.White just wanted to know if you tried `margin:0 auto;` on inner table. Also i would suggest to use it instead of `align="center"` attribute on all the tables, you want to center. Please see above updated answer.

Comment: I tried the new code, it completely solved the issue with the strange right-hand margin on Gmail and appears fine on other clients too. I've implemented the same section of code for the footer bar too and that now works perfectly.

My only issue after adding those snippets was the thin look of the bar in the Gmail app -- solved it with a little padding.

Thank-you for coming to the rescue! :-)

Comment: @S.White I'm glad it helped.